# Python: How to get CSV to write colums (using API)

Tags: python, api, csv

I am trying to create a spreadsheet out of API data, but I am having trouble getting it to work. The .csv file will only contain the last line of information it collected. What I want is 2 columns, both with about 2800 items in each. Instead I have 2 columns with one line in each. Is there a way to write columns instead? I think my problem is that since the `myFile = open('AutoCSV.csv', "w")` is in a for loop it just continues to "open and close" the file? Im pretty new to python and brand new to API and CSV files so any suggestions are appreciated.

```
for x in range(0,5):
string1 = "https://api.rainforestcloud.com/rest/device?networkName=Company&take=500&skip="+str(x*500)
response = requests.get(string1,headers=headers).json()

for y in range (0,499):
    myData = [(response[y]['deviceGuid']),(response[y]['status'])]
    myFile = open('AutoCSV.csv', "w")
    with myFile:
        writer = csv.writer(myFile)
        writer.writerow(myData)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with API nor with the csv format actually, it's just that:

> since the myFile = open('AutoCSV.csv', "w") is in a for loop it just continues to "open and close" the file

Indeed - and not only that but it clears the file each time it reopens it, [as documented here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists)

Also, you're not using `with open()` correctly, you want:

```
with open("path/to/your/file.ext") as f:
    # your code using the file here
```

Hopefully the fix is simple: open the file before your outer loop. Now may I ask why you didn't tried this directly instead of posting here ?

Comment: I did try to open it outside the loop, but then when I run it I  get this error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Comment: This means you tried to use the file outside the `with` block. The point of the `with` block here is to make sure the file will be automagically closed when exiting the block, whatever happens (correct code execution or exception). As I said: start with the `with open(...) as f:` statement AND PUT ALL THE CODE USING THE FILE inside the `with` statement's block.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide any input data, I'll have to do this blindly. Does this works for you?:

```
import csv
import requests

headers = {} #something

with open('AutoCSV.csv', "w", , newline='') as csv_output_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(csv_output_file)

    for current_page_start in range(0, 2500, 500):
        url_to_retrieve = f"https://api.rainforestcloud.com/rest/device?networkName=Company&take=500&skip={current_page_start}"
        json_response = requests.get(url_to_retrieve, headers=headers).json()

        for response_element in json_response:
            data_to_write = (response_element['deviceGuid'], response_element['status'])
            file_writer.writerow(data_to_write)
```